# Why does Google Chrome forget my logins and passwords every time I close it?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cookies

Every time I quit Google Chrome, it clears all of my browser data and cookies.

Why isn't Chrome remembering my accounts and sessions?

Why does Chrome pause syncing my Google account whenever I close the browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Chrome has a setting that can be toggled (sometimes accidentally) that will delete all cookies every time the browser is closed.

As of June 2022 in Chrome 103, the setting is located at **Settings > Privacy and security > Cookies and other site data** (or URL: `chrome://settings/cookies`).

It is called "***Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows***".

That setting should be **disabled** if you wish to preserve logins and cookies between browser sessions.

Comment: This is disabled for me. Happens when Ubuntu runs out of charge

Comment: @StressedBoi_69420 that's because "running out of charge" = "chrome crashes" and therefore it doesn't have the ability to save data before closing, so data is lost. Don't let your laptop run out of charge.

Comment: This setting has been moved to "Privacy and Security > Site Settings > Additional Content Settings > On-Device Site Data"