# Chrome 73.0.3683.86 resets my cookies every day (on reboot)

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, cookies

Cookies for every site I opened on Chrome at my home PC are no longer there when I turn on the PC the next day. 
However, other devices are not affected.

**Oddly, if I restart the PC on the same day, the cookies are still there.**

This had been happening for a few days and I have tried the following solutions:

- Changing "Keep local data only until you quit your browser" option in Chrome,
  as discussed [here](https://superuser.com/q/1333315/150988)
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome
- Reinstalling Windows 10
- Turning on and off CCleaner auto cleaning
- Changing system time
- Checking disk errors

Also, the cookie expiration times are normal
and the cookies file for my Chrome was created by the time I reinstall Chrome.

Comment: What do you mean  by “other devices are not affected”?

Comment: It doesn't happen to me and I have the same Chrome version.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Chrome | Settings Sync options. Mine is set to sync to my gmail account and "Sync on Evertything". All your setting get stored to the cloud so all your devices have access to the same settings.